# vue3 creating global variables returns undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am currently working on upgrading a project to Vue3.  Inside the project we have several files that create global variables inside a boot directory:

```
src/boot/auth.js
src/boot/axios.js
src/boot/cranky.js
....
```

Each of these files creates global variables that I am using throughout the project.  For example my auth.js file:

```js
import auth from '../app/auth';
import { createApp } from 'vue';



export default async ({
    router,
    Vue
}) => {
    const app = createApp({});
app.config.globalProperties.$auth = auth;
    // Vue.prototype.$auth = auth;
    //This works with logic in MainLayout to permit users to see particular screens
    //after they are logged in.
    router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
        if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
            let user;
            if (app.config.globalProperties.$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                // TODO: record screens viewed by router url
                next();
            } else {
                next({
                    path: '/home'
                });
            }
        }
        next();
    });
};
```

After research and reading I understand that global variables are created like this:
`app.config.globalProperties.$auth = auth;`, Which then should be called from other component files using `this.$auth`.  In my case, however, this returns as undefined.

My theory is that there is an issue with my createapp.  Am I calling that correctly, or am I missing something else?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

added code requested by @tony19
The following the full script tag.  My understanding and I probably am wrong, is that the `this` works as a global in vue3.

```html
<script>
import HeaderScoreIndicator from '../components/HeaderScoreIndicator.vue';
import ExitResearchControl from '../components/ExitResearchControl.vue';
import {mq} from 'src/boot/mq'

export default {
    components: {
        HeaderScoreIndicator,
        ExitResearchControl
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            tab: 'denial',
            signedIn: false,
            username: null,
            user: null
        };
    },
    computed: {
        /*
            These 4 functions bind the colors to the background elements
        */
        title: function () {
            return this.$store.state.globals.title;
        },
        toolbarStyle: function () {
            return 'padding-top: 10px; background-color: ' + this.$store.state.globals.toolbarColor;
        },
        footerStyle: function () {
            return `background-color: ${this.$store.state.globals.toolbarColor};`;
        },
        backgroundStyle: function () {
            if(!this.$mq.phone){
                return `background: linear-gradient(180deg, ${this.$store.state.globals.backgroundGradientTop} 0%,  ${this.$store.state.globals.backgroundGradientBottom} 100%);
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;`;
            } else{
                return `background: linear-gradient(180deg, ${this.$store.state.globals.backgroundGradientTop} 0%,  ${this.$store.state.globals.backgroundGradientBottom} 100%);`;
            };
        },
        limitSize: function(){
            if(!this.$mq.phone){
                return 'max-width: 1023px; width: 100%;'
            } else{
                return
            };
        }
    },
    /*
        In the beforeCreate function, we're setting up an event listener to detect
        when we've logged in.  At the successful login we can push the user to
        the correct screen.
    */
    beforeCreate: function () {
        console.log(this.$auth);
        return this.$auth.getState().then(data => {
            if (this.$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                this.username = this.$auth.getEmail();
                return this.initialize(data).then(() => this.signedIn = true);
            } else {
                this.signedIn = false;
                return newUserLanguageSelection()
            }
        }).catch(e => {
            this.signedIn = false;
            console.error(e);
        });

    },
    methods: {
        newUserLanguageSelection: function(){
            if(localStorage.getItem('languageSet') != 'true'){
                    return this.$router.push('/language');
            }
        },
        initialize: function (data) {
            this.$store.commit('globals/dataLoaded');
            this.$store.commit('scoring/setUsername', this.username);
            return this.$store.dispatch('scoring/initializeScoring', { points: data.score | 0 })
                .then(() => {
                    if(this.$store.state.globals.testQuiz){
                        return;
                    } else if(localStorage.getItem('languageSet') != 'true'){
                        return this.$router.push('/language');
                    }else if (data.seenAnalyticsDialog == true) {
                        return this.$router.push('/home');
                    } else {
                        return this.$router.push('/consent');
                    }
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    //silence NavigationDuplicated errors
                    if (e.name != "NavigationDuplicated")
                        throw e;
                });
        }
    }
};

</script>
```

Comment: What is `undefined`? `this`? or `this.$auth`? The context of that code is pertinent. Can you show the code around the `undefined` variable?

Comment: `this.$auth` is coming up undefined.  I will update with the other code.

Answer (score 2):

In the previous Vue 2 project, it looks like `Vue` was passed to the `auth.js` module so that it could attach `$auth` to the Vue prototype.

However, in an attempt to upgrade that particular code in the `auth.js` module to Vue 3, you ignore the `Vue` argument, and create a throwaway application instance to create the `$auth` global property:

```js
// src/boot/auth.js
export default async ({
    router,
    Vue,
}) => {
    const app = createApp({}); ❌ local app instance
    app.config.globalProperties.$auth = auth;
    ⋮
}
```

But that won't work because the `app` instance is not somehow hooked into the application instance you'll eventually mount in `main.js`.

#### Fixing the upgrade

Your `main.js` probably looks similar to this:

```js
// src/main.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import auth from './boot/auth';

auth({ router, Vue });
⋮
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

To correctly upgrade the original code, you should pass the `app` instance from `main.js` to `auth.js`:

```js
// src/main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import auth from './boot/auth';

const app = createApp(App);

auth({ router, app });
⋮
app.mount('#app');
```

And use that `app` in the `auth.js` module:

```js
// src/boot/auth.js
export default async ({
    router,
    app, 
}) => {
     
    app.config.globalProperties.$auth = auth;
    ⋮
}
```

#### Convert to Vue plugin

Assuming you don't need to await the return of the `auth.js` module, you could make that module a [Vue plugin](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html) instead, which automatically receives the `app` instance as the first argument. The second argument receives the options passed in from [`app.use()`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-use):

```js
// src/boot/auth.js
export default {
  install(app, { router }) {
    app.config.globalProperties.$auth = auth;

    router.beforeResolve(⋯);
  }
}
```

```js
// src/main.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import auth from './boot/auth';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(auth, { router });
⋮
app.mount('#app');
```